# Squid and AD authentication

Tags: linux, active-directory, proxy, authentication, squid

I've tried to setup AD authentication according to instructions found at [this link](http://www.papercut.com/kb/Main/ConfiguringSquidProxyToAuthenticateWithActiveDirectory) , but it wasn't successful, AD authentication didn't work.
In cache.log, I've got:
`squid_ldap_auth: WARNING, LDAP search error 'Operations error'` 
I've tried to manually authenticate direct from command line:

`/usr/lib/squid/ldap_auth -R -b dc=central,dc=company,dc=local -D cn=BobanAdmin,cn=Users,dc=central,dc=company,dc=local -w password -f sAMAccountName=boban -h 192.168.0.13 -v 3`

and there was no output, only prompt hanging...
DN and corresponding password are OK, and I'm successfully doing ldapsearch with that credentials.
I've also tried to place quotes to many different places, but with no results.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Where you have put above "cn=Boban Admin," Is there a space in there, or is that just the way the line has rapped around?

Comment: It's a space there.

Comment: I see, well you can't have a space there in the middle of a bash command without escaping it

Comment: THERE'S NO ESCAPING BASH! RAWR!

Comment: I've tried it with Boban\ Admin, "Boban Admin", 'Boban Admin'... No success...

Comment: Use another user not in an organisational unit with a space in the name?!

Comment: I've tried to do this with another binddn, this time with no spaces, cn=BobanAdmin.... Also I had to change argument sAMAccountName=%s with sAMAccountName=boban...  It's still the same.

Comment: Can you post the squid-config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is waiting for a username and password to be entered at the command line. I have to enter the username then a single space then the password and press enter. Now it returns a result...

`root@ubuntu:~# /usr/lib/squid/ldap_auth -R -b "dc=central,dc=company,dc=local" -D "cn=BobanAdmin,cn=Users,dc=central,dc=company,dc=local" -w "password" -f sAMAccountName=%s -h 192.168.0.13` 
After this, it waits for a username and a password:
`boban mypass`
and finally returns:
`OK`